# Something can be estimated therefore it is "estimatable"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

While the meaning of the candidate word *estimatable* would be quite clear, it is not a real English word. Is there such a real English word with the same meaning?

In case it helps, this is based on the [INVEST](http://www.allaboutagile.com/invest-in-good-user-stories/) user stories in Agile<sup>1</sup>. The E stands for *Estimatable* aka "should be be possible to estimate".

I am, of course, happy for such a word not to exist.  If so, how would you phrase it so that it still makes sense in the above context?

---

<sub><sup>**1**: [Erick G Hagstrom](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/129808/erick-g-hagstrom) pointed that the INVEST was coined by [Bill Wake](http://xp123.com/articles/invest-in-good-stories-and-smart-tasks/) who uses `E – Estimable`.</sup></sub>

Comment: If **estimatable* existed, it would mean *it is possible to estimate this*, not *it should be possible..* The difference is important only in technical contexts, of which I would guess AGILE is one.

Comment: Possibly **predictable** if you mean *strongly* estimatable.

Comment: Actually, the E stands for *Estimable*, used to mean *able to be estimated*. Bill Wake created the `INVEST` acronym and wrote the original article on the subject. It can be found at http://xp123.com/articles/invest-in-good-stories-and-smart-tasks/. But like you, I prefer *Estimatable*.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why is *estimatable* not a real English word? The *-able* suffix is productive, and dictionaries very often do not include words which can be deduced from their constituent parts, particularly since they can only include words in reasonably common usage. There is a trade-off: if they do not include words which can be broken down easily and their component parts looked up, there is more space for slightly less common words which can't be deduced as easily.

[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-able?q=-able) has

> **-able** *suffix*
>
> forming adjectives meaning:
>   1. able to be:
>       *calculable*

*Estimatable* means *able to be estimated*.

Comment: +1! I remember once hearing an Italian exchange student tell a Venezuelan (about learning English/vocabulary), "... and if you still can't figure out the right word, make one up. They do it all the time!" Just because we "make up" a word, doesn't mean it's meaningless! Language is about communication, and if a construct is able to clearly convey meaning, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @BrianS Up to a point. *Issual,* for example, is not to be preferred to *issue;* or *expiration* to *expiry*. *-able* can be added to more-or-less anything, but even there there are special forms like *calculable* rather than *calculatable*.

Comment: There's certainly a limit (moderation in all things, etc.), agreed.

Comment: So making up words should be moderable?

Comment: Or moderatable!

Answer (score 6):

*Estimable* certainly is a real English word, and, as any good dictionary will tell you, it means 'worthy of great respect'. It doesn't mean is 'capable of being estimated'. I know of no single word that means that.

Comment: He is saying 'estimatable' isn't a real word, but of course you're right that he's also misusing estimable.

Comment: Thank you. Read too quickly, and I have now edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  I'll blame dyslexia for that one... Silly me.  Of course *estimable* is fine but indeed does not mean 'capable of being estimated'!

Comment: There are dictionaries on the surface web( and not the deep web )which states otherwise(estimable has multiple meaning :worthy of respect and able to be estimated),but I feel (intuition and not innuendo)there must be a better word for being estimable(which a stats person might now @cross validated)-:(using " surface web" is an innuendo(insinuation)that this question could have been easily referred on the net)

Answer (score 2):

As Andrew Leach says in his answer, it is not *not* a real word; in fact, [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22estimatable%22&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5) shows 1880 results of the word "estimatable".

While not a large enough number of uses to make it standard usage, a quick scroll shows that most of the publications are in mathematics and statistics (and, of course, here the results are limited to scholarly articles). The sciences often "create" words, and these words can well become standard usage within a particular field. A similar example would be "rounding", as in "going on rounds", commonly used in nursing but not in standard dictionaries with that definition.

My search for "estimatable" in normal Google mostly brings up either the same sort of usage or questions about its usage (such as this).

As such, I would say it is safe to use in the particular context in which it does currently get used, but not formally elsewhere.

Unfortunately, I don't have any good alternatives off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

**Estimable** means (among other things) 'Capable of being estimated, valued, or appraised' (OED). So no need for 'estimatable', which is probably used because people assume estimable only means 'worthy of esteem or regard'.

(I would say 1880 hits in Google Scholar counts as a 'real word' but I prefer 'estimable' as it was already there, fits the need, is easier to type and sounds far less clunky.)

Comment: That definition is marked "Obs.".

Comment: My 1996 edition of the Oxford Compact English Dictionary does not include "capable of being estimated" as a definition of Estimable.  Possibly the addition is too small to include it or the evolution of the meaning happened more recently.  Esteem and Estimate are quite different words so I am not certain they can be conflated in this way comfortably.  Are you certain it is listed as this in a more recent edition or the OED?

Answer (score -2):

The adjective is **estimative**:

> *adjective*
>
> 1. capable of estimating.
> 2. pertaining to or based upon estimation; estimated.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/estimative)

(Some may pick on the source. Other online sources actually show the definition of *estimate* and indicate that *estimative* is the corresponding adjective.)

Comment: This needs some supporting information such as a dictionary definition of the suggested word.

Comment: This doesn't have the meaning OP requires.

Comment: This means capable of performing estimates, like a good manager or engineer, not capable of being estimated, like a well-understood task.